# Change chart axis labels in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, charts, label

I have a generic chart type which contains points as `List<double>`. How can I programatically change the axis label for each point with a custom label, i.e. use a string instead of the double value?

For example:

```
point1 = (1,5)
point2 = (2,10)
point3 = (3,25)
```

Instead of the x-axis displaying 1,2, and 3, substitute 1 for California, 2 for Arizona, 3 for New Mexico. Thank you.

EDIT: I want to make this change through C#, not using XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi maybe this helps...

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd433476

this part could be interessting for you...

```
 charting : PieSeries.ItemsSource >
   < controls : ObjectCollection >
       < local : ChartPointData Value ="1"
                             Label="Pete" />
       <local:ChartPointData Value="3"
                             Label="David" />
       <local:ChartPointData Value="9"
                             Label="Justin" />
       <local:ChartPointData Value="5"
                             Label="Shawn" />
       <local:ChartPointData Value="5"
                             Label="John" />
   </controls:ObjectCollection>
</charting:PieSeries.ItemsSource>
```

let me know if it helps...

edit:

The article describes that there should be a class like this

```
    public classChartPointData
   {
       public double Value { get; set; }
       public string Label { get; set; }
   }
```

so do not use a Point class do a class with double and string...

Comment: This is in essence what I wish to achieve, but I want to make the changes using C#, not in the XAML. I apologize for not being clear on that point.

Comment: I have edited my answer... the linked article contains a class see my answer and read closely the section about the legend